# How to put the app in a subfolder when using create-react-app in Development mode?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, create-react-app

There are plenty of answers here, and blog posts elsewhere (including official documentation https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/deployment#building-for-relative-paths) explaining how to **build** your react app so that it could be run from a subfolder.

However, I can't find a way how to run it from a subfolder while I'm still in development mode. (i.e. without running: npm run build)

I want to see the app running on localhost:3000/web when I execute: npm start. Not localhost:3000. The static resources that are injected automatically (such as

- src="/static/js/bundle.js"
- src="/static/js/1.chunk.js"
- src="/static/js/main.chunk.js"
- src="/main.947eb2055b7df4ce1a9e.hot-update.js"

  ) should have their path adjusted accordingly to include the app's subfolder name "web".

Is it possible?

Should I "eject" the app and config thing myself?

Should I clone and change "react-scripts start"?

Is there any simpler way?

Thanks

**UPDATE:**

I should have given more details. I do use reverse proxy "http-proxy-middleware" that's the reason I need to run each app in subfolder.
The suggestion below using "basename" of BrowserRouter works for links but not for injected static resources such us "/static/js/bundle.js" The "web" is not added to these when you use "basename", "homepage" and run as: npm start.

So when you run it behind reverse proxy on port 80 it tries to access localhost/static/js/bundle.js which doesn't exist. It should access localhost/web/static/js/bundle.js instead. But as those links are injected automatically I don't have control over adding "web" as a prefix.

Comment: Are you using `BrowserRouter`?

Comment: @ravibagul91 Yes.

Comment: You can always use a reverse proxy or nginx. Ejecting for such a simple thing feels bad :) https://www.npmjs.com/package/hiproxy configuration of this should be easy. And you can add that to your start script

Comment: @DoğancanArabacı thanks for the reply! I actually do use reverse proxy. (See updated question). And that's where it breaks as leading "/" in /static/js/bundle.js force it to go of the host not "web" sub-folder. If you add homepage and do npm build it will work. But not if you do just npm start.

Comment: Oh, I see. Then why not run it in a different port? Do you really need /web in dev ?

Comment: Yes, I run it on the diff ports. Let's say I have 2 apps. 1. Angular on port 8000 and one React on port 3000. I have reverse proxy on port 80. Context /web matches to 3000 and context /web2 to 8000. Urls are rewriten to remove the context from the url path. Angular works. But react doesn't as it's index page needs to either call /web/static/js/bundle.js  or static/js/bundle.js instead it is doing /static/js/bundle.js <- note the leading "/". I understand why the devs choose to make it that way. Thus I wanted to make it work in a "web" subfolder.

Answer (score 3):

When working with `BrowserRouter` you can achieve this, by just adding `basename` as `prop`.

From the [docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter),

> The base URL for all locations. If your app is served from a sub-directory on your server, you’ll want to set this to the sub-directory. A properly formatted basename should have a leading slash, but no trailing slash.

```
<BrowserRouter basename="/web">
  //Your routes
</BrowserRouter>
```

**Note:** Also need to maintain an entry in `package.json` file as

```
"homepage": "http://Domain_name/web",
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply mate. As I wrote in the question I read about how to *build* into a subfolder. I tired that and it works. But that's not what I want. I want it to work without "npm run build" just in dev mode using "npm start".  My understanding "homepage" is only relevant for "build". BrowserRouter will not help with /static/js/bundle.js and alike.

Comment: I have just added note for `build` purpose only (in case you forgot to do this), doning this in development mode also will run your app on `localhost:3000/web`. Give it a try.

Comment: You are right it sort of works. Links use the "web" prefix but static resources are still loaded from /static not from web/static. That breaks things when you run the app behind reverse proxy. Sorry for not mentioning this earlier. I've updated the question.

Comment: This is currently not supported: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8222#issuecomment-568308139. I needed to do the same thing but does not seem possible at this point.

Comment: @eox.dev, *Sorry, but we just don’t support relative urls in development mode! There is a wip PR adding support, but the change is surprisingly complex.*, It means you should use **absolute URL's only**. One more thing, in package.json file if you have `"homepage: "http://localhost/client"`, It won't work either because it is just for production build.